# In Firebase Cloud Messaging, Messaging report, count of received messages is more then sent. Why it is so?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

In Firebase Cloud Messaging, Messaging report, count of received messages is more then sent. Why it is so ?

[image: diagram]

I have checked data in Biq Query and it differs with diagram. In Big Query data count of received messages is less then sent.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

That data is unusual since normally `send` count should be greater than `received`. It’ll be challenging to pinpoint or even narrow down what could be the problem on a public forum without going into project-specific details. The issue can be in the FCM backend itself or just in the reporting metrics. I would recommend reaching out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as they can offer personalized help.